# How to solve conflict when move one git repository to another

Tags: git, repository, git-merge

I have two repositories repo-A and repo-B. I want to move repo-A into repo-B as a subfolder. My question is different from the possible duplicate answer! Please don't mark it without any thinking. I did the following in repo-B by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories):

```
git remote add repo-A url-to-repo-A
git fetch repo-A --tags
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories repo-A/master
```

However, I got the following error:

```
Auto-merging package.json
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in package.json
Auto-merging package-lock.json
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in package-lock.json
Auto-merging README.md
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in README.md
Auto-merging .gitignore
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in .gitignore
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve merge conflicts in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-git)

Answer (score 0):

Question: Are the files in the two repositories A and B supposed to be the same files?  Or do you want all the files in A to be added as a subdirectory and kept as separate files?

solution 1:  Yes, they are the same files and those files need to be merged.
In this case, you need to edit the files to resolve any conflicts. Conflict markers <<< and >>> will be added to the files. You need to edit the files so that they contain the content as you want them to be after merging. Then execute:

```
git add <file>
# after all file conflicts have been resolved and added
git commit
```

Solution 2:  No, the files from repo A should all be in a separate subdirectory and kept separate from the files originally in repo B.  In this case, you want to import repo A into repo B as a subtree. Use the git subtree command:

```
git subtree add -P <prefix> <repository> <ref>
```

for example:

```
git subtree add -P repo-A-dir url-to-repo-A master
```